# Loading 1500 CSV files with sqlldr

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have more than 1500 CSV files to load into Oracle 11gR2. I'm using sqlldr in Windows environment. I know i can load the file as follow, but it a really bad way for many reasons.

```
load data 
infile 'FILE_1.csv'
infile 'FILE_2.csv'
infile 'FILE_3.csv'
infile 'FILE_4.csv'
infile 'FILE_5.csv'
.
.
.
infile 'FILE_1500.csv'
append
into table MyTable
fields terminated by '  '
trailing nullcols
    (   
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        E
        F,
        G
     )
```

I'm looking for an automatic way to load a whole folder of files into the DB, file by file (I don't wan't to merge the files, since they are huge).

Any idea?

Comment: Mention your DB version.

Comment: Did you look at my answer? It would solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently checking your link. Hope to figure out how to do it. These stuff is new for me. Hope it's not a hard one.

Comment: Give it a try, and it would also let you uograde to new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXTERNAL TABLE`, pass the file names to it. On `11gR2`, you could use **PREPROCESSOR DIRECTIVE**.

You could even pass the file names dynamically. Have a look at this asktom link for more details https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3015912000346648463